# Is Isru Chag observed on different days in א"י & בחו"ל?

Tags: chagim-holidays, isru-chag

In other words, is Isru Chag a relative event, like Shavuot, that is actually different outside of Eretz Yisrael?

In the Bavli, Isru Chag is mentioned generically as the day after chag (citing a Tanna, so presumably relevant to EY):

> אמר רבי ירמיה משום רבי שמעון בן יוחי ורבי יוחנן משום רבי שמעון המחוזי משום רבי יוחנן המכותי **כל העושה איסור לחג באכילה ושתיה מעלה עליו** הכתוב כאילו בנה מזבח והקריב עליו קרבן שנאמר אִסְרוּ חַג בַּעֲבֹתִים עַד קַרְנוֹת הַמִּזְבֵּח - **[סוכה מה ע' ב](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.45b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)**

In the Yerushalmi, there is a brief discussion of Isru Chag after Sukkot/Shmini Atzeret, also presumably relevant to EY. It raises [the case in Nechemiah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nehemiah.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) when there was a public fast on 24 Tishrei and asks, why not on 23 Tishrei, which was a yom chol? The answer is, because the 23rd is Isru Chag:

> אמר רב יודן קרייא מסייע ליה, דאמרי חברייא וביום עשרים וארבעה לחודש הזה נאספו בני ישראל בצום ובשקים ואדמה עליהם וגו' (נחמיה ט' א), **ולמה לא אמר בעשרים ושלושה? משום בריה דמועדא** [בריה דמועדא = אסרו חג בלשון הירושלמי] - [**ירושלמי ע"ז א א**](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Avodah_Zarah.1.1.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Rema mentions Isru Chag, presumably בחו"ל, in [א"ח תכט ב](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.429.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ונוהגין להרבות קצת באכילה ושתיה ביום אחר החג והוא אסרו חג

This would seem to indicate after יום טוב שני של גלויות but he's not explicit.

Shibbolei ha-Leket cites the case from the Yerushalmi and adds, again not explicitly:

> ואפילו מוצאי יום טוב צריך אדם לשמוח ולמעט בהספד ובתענית. דכתיב אסרו חג בעבותים אמרה תורה עשו איסור לחג וכתיב בעזרא וביום עשרים וארבעה לחודש הזה נאספו בני ישראל בצום ובשקים וגו' ובירושלמי דע"ז מפרש למה לא עשו כן בעשרים ושלשה שהרי חול היה במוצאי החג הסוכות משום בריה דמועדא **פי' יום שלאחר המועד קרי בריה דמועדא הוא יום אסרו חג כמו שפרשנו ועל כן נהגו שלא ליפול על פניהן (הן) ביום אסרו חג ולא לומר וידוי ואבינו הרחמן אם חל בשני או בחמישי** - ** שבלי הלקט סדר עצרת סימן רסב**

(Sorry, I couldn't find an online source; this text is from bar Ilan.)

Does this mean that למעשה Isru Chag after, say, Sukkot is on 23 Tishrei in EY and 24 Tishrei בחו"ל?

Comment: Practically speaking, isru chag is observed on different days in Eretz Yisrael and Chutz La'aretz. I can't show you anything "inside" right now; that's why this is a comment.

Comment: Isru chag, like chag, is two days long in the diaspora. The first day of isru chag is always the second day of chag, which means it doesn't really matter much.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ah, that's exactly what I was wondering - do you know of a source?

Comment: A source for which part

Comment: Rema OC 494:2 explicitly refers to 8th Sivan as Isru Chag Shavuot

Comment: Ah good find, thanks! (In my ed it’s סע׳ ג)

Comment: @DoubleAA a source for yom tov sheni = isru chag (unless I misunderstood)

Comment: Not sure there is one. It's just by definition. I don't see what the nafka mina is anyway.

Comment: Nafka mina is, eg, does one bechul observe isru chag Pesach on 22 Nisan or 23 Nisan?

Comment: @TamarMarvin Both.